# intellisense type dropdown as a third party tool

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, drop-down-menu, hook, intellisense

I am developing a third party intellisense tool using Visual C++.

I am placing a listbox on a dialog and showing it in keypress(using Win32 hooking). This dialog will show up in any texteditor(notepad,powerpoint,etc). The list will have all the features of the intellisense dropdown as we see in Visual Studio except suggestions(the list is static). The dropdown will every time show a static list of values read from a xml file. User can choose an item from the dropdown and close it.

Please tell me what is the window style i need to use. I tried WS_EX_NOACTIVATE. but the dialog still gaining focus when displayed.

Thanks,
JOhn